# converting RDD to vector with fixed length file data

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I'm new to Spark + Scala and still developing my intuition. I have a file containing many samples of data. Every 2048 lines represents a new sample. I'm attempting to convert each sample into a vector and then run through a k-means clustering algorithm. The data file looks like this:

```
123.34  800.18
456.123 23.16
...
```

When I'm playing with a very small subset of the data, I create an RDD from the file like this:

```
val fileData = sc.textFile("hdfs://path/to/file.txt")
```

and then create the vector using this code:

```
val freqLineCount = 2048
val numSamples    = 200
val freqPowers = fileData.map( _.split(" ")(1).toDouble )
val allFreqs    = freqPowers.take(numSamples*freqLineCount).grouped(freqLineCount)
val lotsOfVecs  = allFreqs.map(spec => Vectors.dense(spec) ).toArray
val lotsOfVecsRDD = sc.parallelize( lotsOfVecs ).cache()

val numClusters = 2
val numIterations = 2
val clusters = KMeans.train(lotsOfVecsRDD, numClusters, numIterations)
```

The key here is that I can call `.grouped` on an array of strings and it returns an array of arrays with the sequential 2048 values. That is then trivial to convert to vectors and run it through the KMeans training algo.

I'm attempting to run this code on a much larger data set and running into `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space` errors. Presumably because I'm calling the `take` method on my freqPowers variable and then performing some operations on that data.

How would I go about achieving my goal of running KMeans on this data set keeping in mind that

1. each data sample occurs every 2048 lines in the file (so the file should be parsed somewhat sequentially)
2. this code needs to run on a distributed cluster
3. I need to not run out of memory :)

thanks in advance

Comment: Thanks. If so answer provided by @RohanAletty should work just fine as long as you sort grouped data by index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
val freqLineCount = 2048
val freqPowers = fileData.flatMap(_.split(" ")(1).toDouble)

// Replacement of your current code.
val groupedRDD = freqPowers.zipWithIndex().groupBy(_._2 / freqLineCount)
val vectorRDD = groupedRDD.map(grouped => Vectors.dense(grouped._2.map(_._1).toArray))

val numClusters = 2
val numIterations = 2
val clusters = KMeans.train(vectorRDD, numClusters, numIterations)
```

The replacing code uses `zipWithIndex()` and division of longs to group RDD elements into `freqLineCount` chunks. After the grouping, the elements in question are extracted into their actual vectors.

Comment: Your missing values sorting.

Comment: Thanks! According to [the docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.5.2/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD), " The ordering is first based on the partition index and then the ordering of items within each partition." Do you happen to know if the partition index is guaranteed to be ordered the same as the original file?